# my html file is disappearing when i run JS code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser, reset

I have an HTML file with a form to fill (name, email, etc) and a reset button that is supposed to empty the value of input fields.
when the button is clicked, a JS method is called

```
function reset()
{
    document.getElementById("Emailinput").value = "";
    document.getElementById("nameinput").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Passwordinput").value = "";   
}
```

when I run the method, the input fields will be cleared but right away I will see "your file was not found" on my browser screen and the html file disappears!
does anyone have an idea what might be the reason?

Comment: The button is also submitting the form (check your browser's address bar). Use [`<input type="reset">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset) for it instead and you can ditch that JS code altogether to boot.

Comment: fixed by adding an input type reset instead of button with event handler. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function `reset` is a global function to clear the page.
By changing the function name you should be able to gain access to your HTML page again. I recommend you use something short and simple, for example `formReset()`.

Answer (score 0):

well in your form you should tell the browser which page to ask for . I didn't see your html code but I guess it looks like that

```
<form action="/somepage">
......
</form>
```

and some page doesn't exists in your js server or in the file browser default server

Comment: True, but not a full answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function name to resetform()
as  there is a builtin Javascript function called reset() to reset the page contents

The fact that your entire HTML page disappears after clicking reset() can be caused if you are using  'document.write()'  function to somewhere in your script or HTML document

please have a look at this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)